# Bootstrap 5 with centering issues on Django template

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates, bootstrap-5

The second element of my cart, which in this case is a nike product, is not aligned and centered like the others.

I would like to know where the problem is in centralizing this element so that it behaves like the others.

when I inspect the page, this element shows wrong padding and margin sizes.

I'm using bootstrap 5.0.2 and Jquery-3.7.0,

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
  <head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>PYTudo</title>
    
   

  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- navbar -->
    <nav class = "navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white py-4 ">
      <div class = "container barra_navegacao">
          <a class = "navbar-brand d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center order-lg-0" href = "/">
              <img src = "/static/base/img/shopping-bag-icon.png" alt = "site icon">
              <span class = "text-uppercase fw-lighter ms-2">Pytudo</span>
          </a>

        <div class="search-form d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center flex-grow-1">
            <form class="d-flex" action="/produtos/listar_produtos/" method="GET">
                <input type="text" class="form-control me-2" name="nome" placeholder="O que você procura?">
            </form>

            <div class="dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link text-uppercase text-dark dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="categoriasDropdown" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Categorias
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="categoriasDropdown">
                    
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class = "order-lg-2 nav-btns">

            <div class="dropdown">
                <button type="button" class="btn position-relative dropdown-toggle" id="PainelDropdown" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <i class="fa fa-address-card" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="PainelDropdown">
                    
                        <li><a href="/accounts/login/">Entrar</a></li>
                    
                    <li><a href="/gestao/painel_controle/">Painel de controle</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <button type = "button" class = "btn position-relative">
                <a href ="/vendas/ver_lista_desejo/"><i class = "fa fa-heart"></i><a/>
                <span class = "position-absolute top-0 start-100 translate-middle badge bg-primary">2</span>
            </button>
            <button type = "button" class = "btn position-relative">
                <a href ="/vendas/carrinho/"><i class = "fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><a/>
                <span class = "position-absolute top-0 start-100 translate-middle badge bg-primary">5</span>
            </button>
        </div>
      </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- end of navbar -->

    
    <section>
        <div class="container py-5 h-100">
          <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
            <div class="col-12">
              <div class="card card-registration card-registration-2" style="border-radius: 15px;">
                <div class="card-body p-0">
                  <div class="row g-0">
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                      <div class="p-5">
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-5">
                          <h1 class="fw-bold mb-0 text-black">Carrinho</h1>
                          <h6 class="mb-0 text-muted">3 items</h6>
                        </div>
                        <hr class="my-4">
      
                        <div class="row mb-4 d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                          <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2">
                            <img
                              src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/new-templates/bootstrap-shopping-carts/img5.webp"
                              class="img-fluid rounded-3" alt="Cotton T-shirt">
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
                            <h6 class="text-muted">Shirt</h6>
                            <h6 class="text-black mb-0">Cotton T-shirt</h6>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 d-flex">
                            <button class="btn btn-link px-2"
                              onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepDown()">
                              <i class="fas fa-minus"></i>
                            </button>
      
                            <input id="form1" min="0" name="quantity" value="1" type="number"
                              class="form-control form-control-sm" />
      
                            <button class="btn btn-link px-2"
                              onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepUp()">
                              <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
                            </button>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 offset-lg-1">
                            <h6 class="mb-0">R$ 44.00</h6>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1 text-end">
                            <a href="#!" class="text-muted"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
      
                        <hr class="my-4">
      
                        <div class="row mb-4 d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                          <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2">
                            <img
                              src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/new-templates/bootstrap-shopping-carts/img6.webp"
                              class="img-fluid rounded-3" alt="Cotton T-shirt">
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
                            <h6 class="text-muted">nike</h6>
                            <h6 class="text-black mb-0">shirt</h6>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 d-flex">
                            <button class="btn btn-link px-2"
                              onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepDown()">
                              <i class="fas fa-minus"></i>
                            </button>
      
                            <input id="form1" min="0" name="quantity" value="1" type="number"
                              class="form-control form-control-sm" />
      
                            <button class="btn btn-link px-2"
                              onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepUp()">
                              <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
                            </button>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 offset-lg-1">
                            <h6 class="mb-0">€ 44.00</h6>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1 text-end">
                            <a href="#!" class="text-muted"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
      
                        <hr class="my-4">
      
                        <div class="row mb-4 d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                          <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2">
                            <img
                              src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/new-templates/bootstrap-shopping-carts/img7.webp"
                              class="img-fluid rounded-3" alt="Cotton T-shirt">
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
                            <h6 class="text-muted">Shirt</h6>
                            <h6 class="text-black mb-0">Cotton T-shirt</h6>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 d-flex">
                            <button class="btn btn-link px-2"
                              onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepDown()">
                              <i class="fas fa-minus"></i>
                            </button>
      
                            <input id="form1" min="0" name="quantity" value="1" type="number"
                              class="form-control form-control-sm" />
      
                            <button class="btn btn-link px-2"
                              onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepUp()">
                              <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
                            </button>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 offset-lg-1">
                            <h6 class="mb-0">€ 44.00</h6>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1 text-end">
                            <a href="#!" class="text-muted"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
                          </div>
                        </div>


                        <hr class="my-4">
      
                        <div class="pt-5">
                          <h6 class="mb-0"><a href="#!" class="text-body"><i
                                class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-left me-2"></i>Continuar Comprando</a></h6>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 bg-grey">
                      <div class="p-5">
                        <h3 class="fw-bold mb-5 mt-2 pt-1">Total</h3>
                        <hr class="my-4">
      
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between mb-4">
                          <h5 class="text-uppercase">3 items</h5>
                          <h5>R$ 132.00</h5>
                        </div>
      
                        <h5 class="text-uppercase mb-3">Entrega</h5>
      
                        <div class="mb-4 pb-2">
                          <select class="select">
                            <option value="1">Standard-Delivery- €5.00</option>
                            <option value="2">Two</option>
                            <option value="3">Three</option>
                            <option value="4">Four</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
      
                        <h5 class="text-uppercase mb-3">Cupom de Desconto</h5>
      
                        <div class="mb-5">
                          <div class="form-outline">
                            <input type="text" id="form3Examplea2" class="form-control form-control-lg" />
                            <label class="form-label" for="form3Examplea2">Enter your code</label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
      
                        <hr class="my-4">
      
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between mb-5">
                          <h5 class="text-uppercase">Preço Total</h5>
                          <h5>R$ 137.00</h5>
                        </div>
      
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-block btn-lg"
                          data-mdb-ripple-color="dark">Finalizar</button>
      
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    






    <!-- footer -->
    <footer class = "bg-dark py-5">
      <div class = "container">
          <div class = "row text-white g-4">
              <div class = "col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                  <a class = "text-uppercase text-decoration-none brand text-white" href ="/">Pytudo</a>
                  <p class = "text-white text-muted mt-3">Loja virtual completa!</p>
                  <p class = "text-white text-muted mt-3">Cadastre os seus produtos e comece a vender agora mesmo!</p>
              </div>

              <div class = "col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                  <h5 class = "fw-light">Links</h5>
                  <ul class = "list-unstyled">
                      <li class = "my-3">
                          <a href = "/" class = "text-white text-decoration-none text-muted">
                              <i class = "fas fa-chevron-right me-1"></i> Home
                          </a>
                      </li>
                      <li class = "my-3">
                          <a href = "#" class = "text-white text-decoration-none text-muted">
                              <i class = "fas fa-chevron-right me-1"></i> Parceiros
                          </a>
                      </li>
                      <li class = "my-3">
                          <a href = "#" class = "text-white text-decoration-none text-muted">
                              <i class = "fas fa-chevron-right me-1"></i> Portifólio
                          </a>
                      </li>
                      <li class = "my-3">
                          <a href = "#" class = "text-white text-decoration-none text-muted">
                              <i class = "fas fa-chevron-right me-1"></i> Sobre nós
                          </a>
                      </li>
                  </ul>
              </div>

              <div class = "col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                  <h5 class = "fw-light mb-3">Contatos</h5>
                  <div class = "d-flex justify-content-start align-items-start my-2 text-muted">
                      <span class = "me-3">
                          <i class = "fas fa-map-marked-alt"></i>
                      </span>
                      <span class = "fw-light">
                          Rua Francisco Floreani, 116 Vila Ema, São Paulo, SP
                      </span>
                  </div>
                  <div class = "d-flex justify-content-start align-items-start my-2 text-muted">
                      <span class = "me-3">
                          <i class = "fas fa-envelope"></i>
                      </span>
                      <span class = "fw-light">
                          marcosfacini5@gmail.com
                      </span>
                  </div>
                  <div class = "d-flex justify-content-start align-items-start my-2 text-muted">
                      <span class = "me-3">
                          <i class = "fas fa-phone-alt"></i>
                      </span>
                      <span class = "fw-light">
                          11 94724-8323
                      </span>
                  </div>
              </div>

              <div class = "col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                  <h5 class = "fw-light mb-3">Redes Sociais</h5>
                  <div>
                      <ul class = "list-unstyled d-flex">
                          <li>
                              <a href = "#" class = "text-white text-decoration-none text-muted fs-4 me-4">
                                  <i class = "fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
                              </a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                              <a href = "#" class = "text-white text-decoration-none text-muted fs-4 me-4">
                                  <i class = "fab fa-twitter"></i>
                              </a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                              <a href = "#" class = "text-white text-decoration-none text-muted fs-4 me-4">
                                  <i class = "fab fa-instagram"></i>
                              </a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                              <a href = "#" class = "text-white text-decoration-none text-muted fs-4 me-4">
                                  <i class = "fab fa-pinterest"></i>
                              </a>
                          </li>
                      </ul>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </footer>
  <!-- end of footer -->

  </body>
</html>
```

My CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kaisei+Tokumin:wght@400;500;700&family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500&display=swap');

:root{
    --lg-font: 'Kaisei Tokumin', serif;
    --sm-font: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    --pink: #e5345b;
}
body{
    font-family: var(--sm-font);
    background-color: #ecedee;
}

/* button */
.bg-primary{
    background-color: var(--pink)!important;
}

.btn a {
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: #000;
}

.btn:hover {
    background-color: #e5345b; 
}

.btn:not(.nav-btns button){
    background-color: #fff;
    color: rgb(85, 85, 85);
    padding: 10px 28px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(85, 85, 85);
}
.btn:not(.nav-btns button):hover{
    background-color: var(--pink);
    color: #fff;
    border-color: var(--pink);
}

/* text color */
.text-primary{
    color: var(--pink)!important;
}

/* navbar */
.navbar{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 9px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            box-shadow: 0 3px 9px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.navbar-brand img{
    width: 30px;
}
.navbar-brand span{
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-family: var(--lg-font);
}
.nav-link:hover{
    color: var(--pink)!important;
}
.nav-item{
    border-bottom: 0.5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.search-form {
    flex: 1; /* Ocupa todo o espaço disponível na navbar */
}

.search-form form {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.search-form input[type="text"] {
    max-width: 300px; /* Define uma largura máxima para a barra de pesquisa */
}

.search-form button {
    margin-left: 10px; /* Espaçamento entre a barra de pesquisa e o botão Pesquisar */
}

.barra_navegacao{
    margin: 0px 20px;
    padding: 0px 12px;
}

/* footer */
footer .brand{
    font-family: var(--lg-font);
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}
footer a{
    -webkit-transition: color 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: color 0.3s ease;
    transition: color 0.3s ease;
}
footer a:hover{
    color: var(--pink)!important;
}

/* media queries */
@media(min-width: 992px){
    .nav-item{
        border-bottom: none;
    }
}


  

.card-registration .select-input.form-control[readonly]:not([disabled]) {
font-size: 1rem;
line-height: 2.15;
padding-left: .75em;
padding-right: .75em;
}

.card-registration .select-arrow {
top: 13px;
}

.bg-grey {
background-color: #eae8e8;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
.card-registration-2 .bg-grey {
border-top-right-radius: 16px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 16px;
}
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
.card-registration-2 .bg-grey {
border-bottom-left-radius: 16px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 16px;
}
}
```